# Why does gradient paint over the entire screen while using CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyPainter(),
        size: Size(100, 100),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final gradient = LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
        Colors.orange,
        Colors.blue,
      ],
    );

    final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height); // Creating fixed Rect
    final shader = gradient.createShader(rect);
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.indigo
      ..shader = shader;
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

I'm passing a size of `100 x 100` to my custom painter, but the gradient painted takes up the entire available space.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: because you did not clip your canvas

Comment: @pskink Thank you, it worked after clipping (using `ClipRRect`, do you have any other way of clipping it inside the `paint` method?). However, if I simply paint a `Rect` using `canvas.drawRect` then it works without clipping. Why is that behavior?

Comment: because `drawRect` draws a specified area (btw that area can extend the "normal" canvas bounds)

Comment: @pskink Alright, so am I only left with wrapping my `CustomPaint` in `ClipRRect` to get the desired behavior?

Comment: not `clipRRect` but `clipRect` - something like:  `canvas.clipRect(Offset.zero & size)`

Comment: @pskink i wrote it as a self-answer (as you always suggest me), however, if you write your own, I'll remove mine. Thank you once again for your efforts.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) as always. A clipping is required before painting.

```dart
canvas.clipRect(Offset.zero & size) 
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
```